# Votes for moderator doesn't drop below 0

Tags: support, status-bydesign, election, voting

I'm not sure if it's supposed to be like that be the number of votes the nominees have doesn't go below 0.

[image: Breakdown of votes on Ronan Forman]

Doing the maths the normal view should display -14 but instead it displays 0
[image: Votes on Ronan Forman]

Is this done on purpose or a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). ([chat link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/475929#475929))

Comment: Ok, does anyone know why? Just curious.

Comment: @Ronan There was talk during the SO election that massively negative scores was unnecessarily demoralizing; the point of the primary is to find the 10 best candidates, not to say "this person is ridiculously awful and deserves hundreds of downvotes"