# Moderator Candidates you have voted up for have a minimum of "1" instead of 0

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, election

I think I have found a small error in the vote display code for the electorship, most likely due to the same mechanics that prevent the showing of negative votes (which has [already been established](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1736/votes-for-moderator-doesnt-drop-below-0) to be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign))

Anyway, pictures are worth a thousand words, right?

[image]

[image]

One would expect the vote total to display 0, rather than +1, yes? I realize this could be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) as well, but thought I'd mention this odd behavior anyway.

---

The same thing happens in reverse - candidates you have voted down have a minimum of -1, instead of 0.

Comment: I see the same behavior.

Comment: It sounds like it may be ceil/floor'ing to 0 and *then* applying the weight of the viewer's vote.  Weird

Comment: I think it's something like `(scoreBeforeVote + abs(scoreBeforeVote))/2 + vote` and S-BD.

Comment: @Matthew - why would it be anything so complicated?

Comment: @ChrisF It's effectively the same as `score = total < 0 ? 0 + vote : total` but I wanted to express it without a conditional because I'm a math nerd.  :P

Comment: @Matthew - now I've looked again it's obvious, but I thought there was something more complicated going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave has the correct answer here - if the candidate has < 0 total score we show 0 and then apply the weight of the viewer's vote.